# Repeatable Parameters in Powershell Function (Preferably Linked Parameter Sets)

Tags: function, powershell, parameters

I am wondering if it is possible (and if so how) to create repeatable (and hopefully linked) parameters in a PowerShell function.  This is how am looking for this to work:

```
function foo()
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Params(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Default")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set1")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set2")]
         [string]$SomeParam1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set1")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set2")]
        *some magic here, likely, to make this repeatable*
         [string]$SomeRepeatableParam,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set1")]
         [string]$SomeLinkedParam1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName="Set2")]
         [string]$SomeLinkedParam2
    )
    Begin
    {
        *some code here*
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach ($val in $SomeRepeateableParam)
        {
            *some code here using param and its linked param*
        }
    }
    End
    {
        *some code here*
    }
}
```

And then call this function like so:

```
foo -SomeParam "MyParam" -SomeRepeatableParam "MyProperty1" -SomeLinkedParam1 "Tall" -SomeRepeatableParam "MyProperty2" -SomeLinkedParam2 "Wide"
```

and so on, being able to use the repeatable parameter as many times in a single call as I feel like it.

Can this be done?  And if so how?

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: For clarity, I don't mean an array parameter, but a repeatable parameter in which the linked parameter sets can be matched to each instance of the repeatable parameter.

Comment: Given your update I think I am more confused. do you want users to be able to specify the same parameter multiple times (pairs)? How is that less confusing than an object like an array? At a minimum you can't have parameters with non unique names. If you are worried about your users then why not create a help section which what that is for. Pairs just sounds like a hashtable array which would help the values not get lost.

Comment: @Matt Because it more like condensing multiple function calls into one, which for some of the people using this is ideal.  The function in question can be written to be called several times to do its updates with no problem, and the people involved can handle that, but explaining the specs of the linked arrays or properties of custom objects might stretch their tolerance.  They're not dumb, just narrow focused, so I am trying to be accommodating.  I accept it may not be possible, and I have a fallback that would use multiple calls or an object array, I just want to see if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since PowerShell supports *arrays* as parameter values, there is generally no need to *repeat* a parameter.

There is no *syntactic* way to enforce the *pairing* (linking) of parameter values the way you intend, with repeating instances of the same parameter name, because parameter names must be *unique* (and even they didn't have to be unique, that alone wouldn't enforce the desired *pairing*).

You can, however, use parallel *array* parameters, and enforce their symmetry *inside the function*, e.g.:

```
function foo
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
         [string]   $SomeParam1,
         [string[]] $SomeRepeatableParam,
         [string[]] $SomeLinkedParam
    )
    if ($SomeRepeatableParam.Count -ne $SomeLinkedParam.Count) {
      Throw "Please specify paired values for -SomeRepeatableParam and -SomeLinkedParam"
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $SomeRepeatableParam.Count; ++$i) {
       $SomeRepeatableParam[$i] + ': ' + $SomeLinkedParam[$i]
    }
}
```

You would then call it as follows (note the `,` to separate the array elements):

```
foo -SomeParam1 "MyParam" `
    -SomeRepeatableParam "MyProperty1", "MyProperty2" `
    -SomeLinkedParam     "Tall",        "Wide"
```